# Reference on the Open and Closed migration processes

Tags: probability

I have read part of Frank Kelly's book on  Open and Closed migration processes and I would like to find out a bit more. I am not an expert on the area with only some basic knowledge in continuous Markov Chains, queueing theory and renewal processes. I have done some googling myself, but is there any paper people would particularly recommend?